# Do not understand behavior of wpf updating dynamically created image control visibility changing every seconds

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, grid

I have a Grid with 8 rows and 8 columns in wpf:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="560" Width="800">
    <Grid x:Name="MyGrid" ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

the code behind is:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private const int MaxRow = 8;
        private const int MaxCol = 8;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Start()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < MaxRow ; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < MaxCol ; j++)
                {
                    string current = $"ImgR{i}C{j}";
                    object currentImg = this.FindName(current);

                    if (currentImg?.GetType() == typeof(Image))
                    {

                        var img = ((Image)currentImg);

                        Thread.Sleep(1500);
                        img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        DoEvents();

                        Thread.Sleep(1500);
                        img.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                        DoEvents();
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var pngImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Test\cross.png", UriKind.Absolute));
            for (int i = 0; i < MaxRow ; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < MaxCol; j++)
                {
                    var img = new Image
                    {
                        Source = pngImage,
                        Name = $"ImgR{i}C{j}",
                        Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
                    };

                    Grid.SetRow(img, i);
                    Grid.SetColumn(img, j);
                    MyGrid.Children.Add(img);
                    RegisterName($"ImgR{i}C{j}", img);
                }
            }
            Start();
        }


        public static void DoEvents()
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                new Action(delegate { }));
        }
    }
```

[image]

so the idea is that I dynamically create `8x8` images, and register them. Then  in two loops I change its visibility. So the resulting effect is that an image cross traverses a `8x8` grid
Program seems to do it correctly, however the transition is not smooth **sometimes**, I mean, the cross changes its visibility but ocasionally (program generally works well) does not show.

I guess the problem is when I update the Ui using:

```
public static void DoEvents()
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                new Action(delegate { }));
        }
```

Is there a better way to do this, or what could be the issue that cross sometimes does not show.

Answer (score 2):

WPF GUI updates are done in the GUI thread, but you're locking that thread up with `Thread.Sleep` in your Start function, which is called by the window `Loaded` event handler, which is itself called by the GUI thread. I can see what you're trying to do with your `DoEvents` function, but that's not a reliable way to update the GUI thread (you're already on the GUI thread to begin with, so you're relying on some unknown internal behavior of the framework to force an update).

Concurrent programming is not a trivial thing, I would recommend you read up on it before going any further. For starters, you should never call `Thread.Sleep()`. Threads are obsolete in C# and have been replaced by asynchronous programming (which may or may not use threads internally, but that doesn't usually concern the application developer). What you need to do here is modify your Start function to be asynchronous i.e. something like this:

```
private async Task Start()
{           
    for (int i = 0; i < MaxRow; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < MaxCol; j++)
        {
            string current = $"ImgR{i}C{j}";
            object currentImg = this.FindName(current);

            if (currentImg?.GetType() == typeof(Image))
            {

                var img = ((Image)currentImg);

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500));

                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                });


                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500));

                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    img.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your loaded function you start the task with:

```
private CancellationTokenSource CancelSource;
...
this.CancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task.Run(Start, this.CancelSource.Token);
```

The cancellation token source is then used if you need to cancel the task, e.g. if the user closes the window:

```
this.CancelSource.Cancel();
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried the code and for me I cannot even see the cross, in fact the window hangs. This is what I am expecting.

You are calling the `Start` method in the UI thread and running a loop through it or putting a Thread.Sleep. Both actions are blocking, i.e. they will use the resources in the UI thread and the window will hang.

To get around this you should start the method in a background method/task. The following should work. Instead of calling `Start` directly try this:

```
Task.Run(() => Start());
```

Also I do not understand your Do Events method, plus since now your entire Start method is in background, you will have to make sure that you take care of cross threaded operations. You will further have to add appropriate exception handling.

```
    private void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MaxRow; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < MaxCol; j++)
            {
                string current = $"ImgR{i}C{j}";
                object currentImg = Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.FindName(current));

                if (currentImg?.GetType() == typeof(Image))
                {

                    var img = ((Image) currentImg);

                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible);

                    //DoEvents();

                    //Thread.Sleep(100);
                    //Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible);
                    //DoEvents();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```